# Nginx subdomain redirection using SSL not working

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, docker-compose

I have a domain **example.com**. I'd like to run multiple applications over its subdomains and enable https over them.

I have used certbot to create a certificates for the ***.example.com** and **example.com** domains.

There are three applications which handle the requests from different subdomains.

1. Application **`app1`** handles the request from the subdomain **abc.example.com** **only**.
2. Application **`app2`** handles the request from the subdomains of the form **[some_name].example.com**.
3. Application **`app3`** handles the request from the **example.com** **only**.

I am facing the following problems.

1. When I try to access the domain **abc.example.com** from the browser, it redirects to **www.abc.example.com**, which then gives an invalid certificate error.
2. Using the regular expression for server name causes all the requests to be redirected to the **app1**.
3. When I try to access the domain **example.com** from the browser, it redirects to **www.www.abc.example.com**, which is an invalid domain.

I am not sure what seems to be the problem. Is it the regex for server name?
Also, is there any other better way which can be used for this scenario?
Any help is appreciated.

**Note:**
The applications are hosted as docker containers in the same docker network.

---

The following is the nginx conf file.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  charset utf-8;
  access_log off;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com;

  server_tokens off;
  ssl on;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem;

  ssl_buffer_size 8k;

  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

  ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  # OCSP stapling
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8;

  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}


server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_tokens off;

  ssl on;

  ssl_buffer_size 8k;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

  ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  # OCSP stapling
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app3:80;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  charset utf-8;
  access_log off;
  server_name abc.example.com;

  location / {
     rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name abc.example.com;

  server_tokens off;
  ssl on;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

  ssl_buffer_size 8k;

  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

  ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  # OCSP stapling
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app1:80;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  charset utf-8;
  access_log off;
  server_name ~^(?!abc|www).+\.example\.com$ ~^www\.(?!abc|www).+\.example\.com$;

  location / {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name ~^(?!abc|www).+\.example\.com$ ~^www\.(?!abc|www).+\.example\.com$;

  server_tokens off;
  ssl on;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

  ssl_buffer_size 8k;

  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

  ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  # OCSP stapling
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app2:80;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not look like that these redirects are caused by the config you show. Maybe there are caused by config you don't show, specifically by the apps running inside the container.

Comment: These apps are running on different ports and are completely unrelated. Additionally, I'd like to point out that they work perfectly if I don't use SSL.

Comment: The apps are not completely unrelated since your nginx setup is just a reverse proxy for these apps and it is possible to issue the redirects you see from inside the apps. As I said - no part of the configuration you show is responsible for these redirects so it must be something you don't show.

Comment: I meant that these apps are not issuing any redirects outside their scope.

Comment: *"I meant that these apps are not issuing any redirects outside their scope."* - this might be true but the configuration you show does not cause such redirects either. But given that these redirects actually happen something does not work as expected. From my understanding of your config the cause of the problem is not the config you've shown in your question so it has to be somewhere which is not shown.

Comment: Is there any configuration which prevents the 'www' prefix from being added in the address bar for the browser? For instance when I navigate to stackoverflow, then the browser doesn't add the 'www' prefix, but when I navigate to google, then the browser adds the 'www' prefix.

Comment: There does not need any configuration to prevent this since it is not done by the browser by its own. The only reason this happens with some sites is that the site explicitly issues a redirect - which has to be configured in the servers configuration or issued by the web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the clues from **@Steffen Ullrich**, I finally got this working.

I removed all the redirects to **www.example.com** and **www.*.example.com**.

Specifically, the following server block.

```
server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_tokens off;

  ssl on;

  ssl_buffer_size 8k;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

  ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  # OCSP stapling
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app3:80;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

Additionally, I changed the regex for wildcard server names from `~^(?!abc|www).+\.example\.com$ ~^www\.(?!abc|www).+\.example\.com$` to `~^(?!api|www)\w+\.example\.com$`